# Subroutines and functions that cannot be accessed through object browser

Tags: excel, vba

Recently, I tried to access to some subroutines and functions in an Excel file (in .xlsm format) that have been developed in the past.

Initially,  I found that those subroutines and functions are not present under the module folder.

Instead, I tried to retrieve those subroutines and functions with object browser under "VBAProject".

However, I found that I am unable to view the codes of those subroutines and functions by double clicking those subroutines and functions.

May I ask if there are solutions to the access of the codes?

Thank you.

The situation in normal condition:

[image]

---

More details on 4 July 2022:

What I can see in the project explorer is a module (double clicking the module shows no codes.), while in the object browser, the Class is the module mentioned and the Library is called "VBAProject". I know there are some methods of hiding codes but I did not experience such situation in the past.

Comment: Looks strange. Doesn't right click and `View Definition` help either?

Comment: What happens when you double click Module1 in the project explorer

Comment: To freeflow: double clicking the module shows no codes.

Comment: To ENIAC: Tried to click "View Definition but unable to access the codes.